# In which case could "a != a" return "true"?

Tags: java, numbers, equality, nan

[java.lang.Math#min(double, double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28double,%20double%29):

```java
public static double min(double a, double b) {
    if (a != a) return a; // a is NaN
    if (a == 0.0d && b == 0.0d && Double.doubleToLongBits(b) == negativeZeroDoubleBits) return b;
    return (a <= b) ? a : b;
}
```

In which case could `a != a` return `true`? It seems that it's when `a` is NaN, but I can't imagine an example. Could you please provide one?

Comment: a will always equal a no matter what, that line does nothing.
im surprised that your IDE doesn't call it unreachable code.

Comment: @tommycake50 Wrong. See below answers. Comparing NaNs for equality always return false.

Comment: The answer is in the comment of the code in the question ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple example is

```
double d = Double.NaN; // or
double d = 0.0/0.0; // or
double d = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY + Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
if (Double.isNaN(a)) { // tests if a != a
   // do something
```

BTW Double.compare() does see NaN as equal

```
if (Double.compare(d, d) == 0) // always.
```

With multiple threads this is possible for any type and value. e.g.

```
if (a != /* another thread changes 'a' */ a) {
    // a thread changed a while you were looking at it.
```

Comment: Your second point is very interesting... does the JLS require that each occurence of a `volatile a` within the same expression results in a separate read action? If not, then this would be just an artifact of a specific implementation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I believe every access is decrete access until the JIT optimises the code at which point, volatile will still be individual accesses.

Comment: Since `Double.NaN` is a constant, I feel quite perturbed that `Double.NaN != Double.NaN` though... `Double.NaN` is one single *not-a-number* instance, thus I would have thought that `not-a-number == not-a-number`, just like `banana == banana`. But yeah, obviously not, thank you anyway `;)`

Comment: @sp00m: I would consider the fact that `NaN` is neither greater than, less than, nor equal to any *other* value a good design.  I consider the fact that it compares unequal to itself a *bad* design.  When comparing the results of floating-point operations, `(a/b)==(c/d)`, doesn't really the two fractions are precisely equal; it means they're numerically indistinguishable--a trait which would be just as true of when comparing (0f/0f) and (NaN/NaN) as it would be when comparing (16777215f/16777216f) and (16777214f/16777215f).

Answer (score 0):

If a is NAN, and NAN is for example divide by zero

min(0.0f/0.0f, 0.0f)

Comment: 1f/0f is positive infinity, not NaN