# How can a Java variable be different from itself?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am wondering if this question can be solved in Java (I'm new to the language). This is the code:

```
class Condition {
    // you can change in the main
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int x = 0;
        if (x == x) {
            System.out.println("Ok");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not ok");
        }
    }
}
```

I received the following question in my lab:

*How can you print "Not ok" without modifying the condition?*

**Edit**

*How can you skip the first case (i.e. make the `x == x` condition false) without modifying the condition itself?*

Comment: I believe there should be more restriction, otherwise it is too open.

Comment: Which parts of the code may you change, if any?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can "while (i == i) ;" be a non-infinite loop in a single threaded application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471296/how-can-while-i-i-be-a-non-infinite-loop-in-a-single-threaded-applicati)

Comment: Is it as simple as `System.out.println("Gotcha!");` instead of the comment? :)

Comment: What type is a? String Object double?

Comment: Whatever type you want;

Comment: Good, then is double a= Double.NaN the shortest answer and my "hack is just a cheat ;)

Comment: This is cute Java trivia, but I hope no one will consider making it an interview question.  People considering candidates for employment should be doing the best they can to figure out if the candidate understands programming, not how much trivia he's accumulated.  I've barely used floating point numbers in 17 years of programming in Java, much less the NaN construct, MUCH less knowing how it behaves with the == operator...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471296/how-can-while-i-i-be-a-non-infinite-loop-in-a-single-threaded-applicati and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460416/in-which-case-could-a-a-return-true

Comment: A bit over the top would be to define a class that overrides the `==` operator and always returns false, then instaniate that class as `a`

Comment: @user1158692 Within java you can't override basic operators like `==`

Comment: @user1158692 Take it to slashdot.

Comment: @user1158692 Matter of opinion, I personally hate any programs where the basic operators have been overridden and am glad that any code I recieve in java hasn't been messed with (I have seen * overridden as the [vector cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) and the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) because both are kinds of vector multiplication; infuriating! Whereas in java one is called `.cross()` and the other is `.dot()` and there is no confusion. Also the fact that "override the == operator and always return false" can't happen seems pro java

Comment: it may be confusing sometimes, but reading myObj == yourObj it's a bit more clear than myObj.equals(yourObj).

Comment: @AndreDurao Ah but in java `myObj == yourObj`  means **truly and faithfully the same object** whereas `.equals()` means "looks the same", they are seperate concepts and we need both of them

Comment: @rcook knowing about NaN, where it comes from, and how it behaves is pretty important. Almost every major language has it (and it behaves in the same way in all) and doing it wrong is liable to add very tricky bugs to any code that does non-integer maths.

Comment: @RichardTingle you can just as easily override the `.equals()` method to always `return false;`

Comment: in addition to answers given, there's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19434552/365237)

Comment: And after questions merged nobody can understand what gotcha everybody is talking about in this post.

Comment: @RichardTingle there's absolutely no confusion when it comes to overloaded vector cross and dot multiplication, even if you were to throw in matrix multiplication into the mix: the signatures are quite different enough so it's always obvious which form of multiplication is being applied. That said, what kind of language allows that sort of overloading, anyway? It kinda sounded like a stab at C++, but in C++ you can't have two overloads with the same argument and different result types...

Comment: @Magnus I mean one library overloading one way and a **different** library overloading the other way, and I am talking about C++. And it's just an example;  the point is I like to know what my functions do just from the name; the docs should support that, not be essential

Comment: @RichardTingle I see... well, mathematically speaking it's perfectly sensible to use the * operator for a dot product because that's how vector spaces are defined in pretty much any linear algebra textbook, and I was arguing that the types involved tend to make it very clear what an operation does. I know it's just an example, but I honestly can't see the confusion because I really do think it's very clear in that context and it makes the code a lot easier to read. Can't even think of a really atrocious example either.

Comment: I'm glad I came across this so I can know how not to ask an absurd "look how smRT" I am question as an instructor. I would strongly question the productivity of the person who designed this question -- oh wait, its a teacher...

Answer (score 177, accepted):

One simple way is to use [`Float.NaN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NaN):

```
float x = Float.NaN;  // <--

if (x == x) {
    System.out.println("Ok");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not ok");
}
```

```
Not ok
```

You can do the same with [`Double.NaN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN).

---

From [**JLS §15.21.1.** Numerical Equality Operators `==` and `!=`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1):

> Floating-point equality testing is performed in accordance with the rules of the IEEE 754 standard:
>
> - If either operand is NaN, then the result of `==` is `false` but the result of `!=` is `true`.
>
>   Indeed, the test `x!=x` is `true` if and only if the value of `x` is NaN.
>
> ...

Answer (score 160):

```
int x = 0;
if (x == x) {
    System.out.println("Not ok");
} else {
    System.out.println("Ok");
}
```

Comment: Heh, this totally answers the question as asked.

Comment: Well if you take this path then just put a `;` after the `if` and print `"Not ok"` directly. However I don't believe this is what the OP was after.

Comment: @arshajii: If there is a semi-colon after the if, then there will be an error for the else part ..

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Right, but if we are taking the question completely literally as this answer does, then we can delete the `else` altogether. This wouldn't technically violate the terms of the question.

Comment: Considering this is my second highest voted answer I'm not sure whether to conclude that I'm very funny or a crappy programmer.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Given the requirements, I think this is the most KISS/YAGNI/appropriate answer  ;)

Comment: Problem solving isn't programming. You won because you resolved this problem changing the point of view and I think this is the expected answer. +1

Comment: The question was "How can you skip the first case", so this answer is wrong.

Comment: @jddsantaella: obviously this was edited afterwards. The original question said "How can I print 'not ok'".

Comment: You forgot the most important and final line required:
`// yourQuestion == PWND!`

Answer (score 148):

By the [Java Language Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) `NaN` is not equal to `NaN`.

Therefore any line that caused `x` to be equal to `NaN` would cause this, such as

```
double x=Math.sqrt(-1);
```

From the Java Language Specifications:

> Floating-point operators produce no exceptions (§11). An operation
>   that overflows produces a signed infinity, an operation that
>   underflows produces a denormalized value or a signed zero, and an
>   operation that has no mathematically definite result produces NaN. All
>   numeric operations with NaN as an operand produce NaN as a result. As
>   has already been described, NaN is unordered, so **a numeric comparison
>   operation involving one or two NaNs returns false** and any !=
>   comparison involving NaN returns true, including x!=x when x is NaN.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ A fair point, I was so busy going off to find said "coding convention" that I forgot to actually answer the question

Comment: This is only valid if a is declared as Object or double.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach True, in the absence of any information to the contrary I have assumed the commented out line can be anything

Comment: Even my cheated answer is correct and fulfills the rules. I edited only before the if-statement and only "Gotcha! is printed out. I'am sure, that this answer is not the answer in the mind of the creator of this riddle. But the riddle is not well defined (as most softwareprojects).

Answer (score 73):

Not sure if this is an option but changing `x` from local variable to a field would allow other thread to change its value between the reading left and right side in `if` statement.

Here is short demo:

```
class Test {

    static int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Change());
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();

        while (true) {
            if (x == x) {
                System.out.println("Ok");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not ok");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Change implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while (true)
            Test.x++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
⋮
Ok
Ok
Ok
Ok
Ok
Ok
Ok
Ok
Not ok
```

Comment: Haha +1 for effort, but man...there's no way anyone in *my* Java lab would have come up with something like this (instructor included).

Comment: @WilliamGaul Really? I always though that it is one of basic examples showing possible problems with multithreading and why people who think that this subject is easy should never be in charge of anything :)

Answer (score 56):

The replaced line could read.

```
double x = Double.NaN;
```

This would cause the gotcha to be printed.

Java Language Specification (JLS) says:

> Floating-point operators produce no exceptions (§11). An operation that overflows produces a signed infinity, an operation that underflows produces a denormalized value or a signed zero, and an operation that has no mathematically definite result produces NaN. All numeric operations with NaN as an operand produce NaN as a result. As has already been described, NaN is unordered, so a numeric comparison operation involving one or two NaNs returns false and any != comparison involving NaN returns true, including x!=x when x is NaN.

Comment: Or lead into a compile error, if a is declared as String a = "Nope"; That why I asked for the type of 'a'

Comment: The code above gives no information about types, therefore I have made the assumption that a is not already defined.

Comment: I think that your answer is the answer, that was in the mind of the riddle creator. But the rules were not clear. Only two rules were given: 1. only insert in the line with the comment and 2. only get one "Gotcha! printed out.

Comment: the riddle author could have made always valid by surrounding the code in { }

Answer (score 30):

I managed to get a `Gotcha!` from this:

```
volatile Object a = new Object();

class Flipper implements Runnable {
  Object b = new Object();

  public void run() {
    while (true)  {
      Object olda = a;
      a = b;
      a = olda;
    }
  }

}

public void test() {
  new Thread(new Flipper()).start();

  boolean gotcha = false;
  while (!gotcha) {
    // I've added everything above this - I would therefore say still legal.
    if (a == a) {
      System.out.println("Not yet...");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Gotcha!");
      // Uncomment this line when testing or you'll never terminate.
      //gotcha = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This changes more than just the comment as the question asks for.

Comment: I've tried something like that that but I think that it's guaranteed that it will produce the same result always, isn't it?

Comment: @Mex - It does indeed but it preserves enough of the original to demonstrate a further key point that sometimes `a != a` because it was changed by another thread. I suspect this would win points in an interview.

Comment: This is actually quite clever though, I assume this works by "hoping" that `a` is altered by the first thread in-between the first and second access for comparison

Comment: @RichardTingle - Not just a hope - I got a real one when I ran it on my multi-core PC.

Comment: I think, that this solution is against the rules. It says "Instead of this comment..." So I think you weren't allowed to change the following code.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Ah but I assume theoretically this program could run forever without hitting that. It's just very very likely to hit it quickly

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach Completely true, but I'm going to +1 it just for sheer inventiveness

Comment: Re your doubters; it's worth noting that everything you've written above the key `if` statement could be written in a single horrible line if necessary

Comment: @RichardTingle I think this sort of assumes that this code is within a method. If you add class and method headers to this, then you have to add extra code after the code mentioned, even if just braces, which is against the rules. For any program that contains that if block, that would compile if a existed, would not compile if you pasted the stuff that's above it here. Maybe if you made some anonymous classes inside the method would work though. In any case, I upvoted this. This is my favourite answer and the first thing I thought of when reading the problem

Answer (score 27):

There are so many solutions:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

class A extends PrintStream {
    public A(PrintStream x) {
        super(x);
    }

    public void println(String x) {
        super.println("Not ok");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setOut(new A(System.out));
        int x = 0;
        if (x == x) {
            System.out.println("Ok");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that `super.println` should be "Not ok", right?

Comment: @Izkata Yes, didn't recheck what the desired output should be.

Answer (score 26):

One easy solution is:

```
System.out.println("Gotcha!");if(false)
if( a == a ){
  System.out.println("Not yet...");
} else {
  System.out.println("Gotcha!");
}
```

But I don't know all the rules to this riddle...

**:)**
I know that this is a cheat, but without knowing all rules, is this the easiest solution to the question :)

Comment: A clever answer, as the comment doesn't say HOW the Gotcha! should be printed, however I think this counts as two lines. :p

Comment: Can be written in one line ;)

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach As can all programs

Comment: I think a switch statement won't compile.

Comment: `int b=1; switch(b){case 1: System.out.println("woo"); break; case 2: System.out.println("boo");break;}` is a single line, compiles and prints "woo" (as all good programs should)

Comment: Yes I tried it, too. I think my "in-brain" compiler just stops, if the code is too far away from codeing standards....

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach In all fairness the compiler should immediately delete all files on your computer if you tried to actually program like that

Comment: Why make it so difficult? `if (System.out.println("Gotcha") && false)`

Comment: error: 'void' type not allowed here
if(System.out.println("Gotcha")&& false)

Your code won't compile...

Comment: Actually it doesn't say that you can't have "not yet..." printed so just print gotcha and let the rest runs as usual

Answer (score 14):

Create your own class `System` in tha same package with `Condition`.
In this case your `System` class will hide `java.lang.System` class

```
class Condition
{
    static class System
    {
        static class out
        {
            static void println(String ignored)
            {
                java.lang.System.out.println("Not ok");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int x = 0;
        if (x == x) 
        {
           System.out.println("Not ok");
        } 
        else 
        {
           System.out.println("Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

[**Ideone DEMO**](http://ideone.com/F039qY)

Answer (score 10):

Using the same skip/change output approach from another answers:

```
class Condition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int x = 1 / 0;
            if (x == x) {
                System.out.println("Ok");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not ok");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can you **skip the first case** without modifying the condition itself?

"E.g." part in such questions should NOT mislead you. More ideas from my side:

```
class Condition1 {
    // you can change in the main
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int x = 0;
        if (x == x) /*{
            // the most popular method in actual debug, don't you think?
            System.out.println("Ok");
        } else */{
            System.out.println("Not ok");
        }
    }
}

class Condition2 {
    // you can change in the main
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int x = 0;
        if (x == x); if (false) {
            System.out.println("Ok");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not ok");
        }
    }
}

class Condition3 {
    // you can change in the main
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("Not ok");
    }

    private void ignored() {
        int x = 0;
        if (x == x) {
            System.out.println("Ok");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not ok");
        }
    }
}

class Condition4 {
    // you can change in the main
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int x = 0;
        if (false) {
            return; // this becomes "the first case" and it's skipped
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not ok");
            return;
        }
        if (x == x) {
            System.out.println("Ok");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not ok");
        }
    }
}


import static Condition5.Container.x;

class Condition5 {

    static class Container {
        static int x = new Inner().hashCode();
    }

    private static class Inner {
        public Inner() {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            {
                int x = 0;
            }
            if (x == x) {
                System.out.println("Ok");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not ok");
            }
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println("Not ok");
        }
    }
}
```