# About the semantics of a simple Java program

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider a Java class `A` as follows, where `f` is a `Integer` field of `A`, and `u` is a local `Integer` variable of the method `foo()` in class `A`.

```
class A{

     int f; 

    void foo(){  
       int u;
    ... 
       f = 7;
       u = f;
    ...
   }
    ....
}
```

Is it wrong to claim that:

```
       variable ‘u’ MUST be 7 at the end of “f=7; u =f;”?
```

My opinion is that ‘f’ may be changed by other threads, so the claim above should be false in general. Am I right?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Yes, [even x==x can be false](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19416907/2187042) (ignoring any NaN!=NaN malarki)  when threads get involved. However I expect this statement has a silent assumption of single threadedness

Comment: Thanks. So am I correct in assuming  x == x is not a unit operation in Java?

Comment: Correct, few things are. [Even i++ is not atomic](http://madbean.com/2003/mb2003-44/). But [atomic variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html) exist to solve this problem

Comment: @RichardTingle is right. But you said "false in general" and i can't agree with you: multithreading couldn't be included as 'in general'. So your statement is wrong then it comes to multithreading and true otherwise (single threading). Don't mix theese two things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes execution could be interrupted between f=7, u=f. You call this a critical area which could be secured using locks, mutexes or semaphores. This way you make sure that no other thread (or even hardware interrupt, well not in java ;)) changes your data without definately wanting it.

Answer (score 2):

In a multi threaded environmend an other Object from a class in the same package as class A could access the Attribute f (because it is not `private`) and change f to an other value e.g. `5`. This Step could be executed between the two statements `f = 7;` and `u = f;`. So `f` could be changed befor assigning to it `u`. This means you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Multi threaded code can be tricky to get right if not implemented properly. In your case you are right that there is no guarantee that u will be 7 if your application is multi threaded. See if the sample code I have helps it make more clear.

```
public class Test {
    private int f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Test test = new Test();

        new Thread("Thread 1") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                test.modifyF();
            }
        }.start();
        test.foo();
    }

    private void modifyF() {
        new Thread("Thread 1") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                f = 9;
                System.out.println("F is set by " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ". Now  f = " +f);
            }
        }.start();
    }
    private void foo() {
        int u;
        f = 7;
        System.out.println("F is set by " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ". Now f = " +f);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        u = f;
        System.out.println("U = " + u);
        System.out.println("F = " + f);
    }
}
```

**Output:**
F is set by main. Now f = 7 
F is set by Thread 1. Now  f = 9
U = 9
F = 9

I have used thread sleep to demonstrate the issue. If your application is mutithreaded proper use of synchronization can help in making no two threads modify the variable "f" at the same time.