# while(i != i) { } - is it possible to have an assignment that is always true

Tags: java, variables, while-loop, variable-assignment

Recently I had an interview with a Software company where the following question was asked in the technical aptitude round:

Declare i in such a way that the condition is always true :

```
while(i != i) {
}
```

Is it technically possible in java to assign something of this sort??

Comment: Why not?  I think it should be possible given that you have declared the value of i earlier and are not changing it's value inside the loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416644/how-can-a-java-variable-be-different-from-itself

Comment: my gut feeling is that it may be related to lambdas in Java-8. For example in scala we can assign a function to a variable and the actual evaluation of variable happens not after assignment but at the time of  evaluation. For example `def i = Math.random` will give different values for i every time `i` is evaluated. Not sure if something like that possible is Java-8 too.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460416/in-which-case-could-a-a-return-true) post can make it clear for you

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`NaN` is not equal to itself, so

```
double i = Double.NaN;
```

But I don't think this is a good interview question.

Quote from the Java Language Specification:

> NaN is unordered, so:
>
> - The numerical comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` return `false` if    either or both operands are `NaN` (§15.20.1).
> - The equality operator `==` returns `false` if either operand is `NaN`.     In particular, `(x<y) == !(x>=y)` will be `false` if `x` or
>     `y` is `NaN`.
> - The inequality operator `!=` returns `true` if either operand is `NaN` (§15.21.1). In particular, `x!=x` is `true` if and only if `x`
>     is `NaN`.

Comment: pretty obscure.  Do you have some javadocs?

Comment: @ScaryWombat check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819738/why-does-double-nan-double-nan-return-false there is a link to the java-doc in the answere :)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Cheers

Comment: @DAle Thank you so much :)